# Vectors generating a space

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I have the following question to solve:

> Find, among $\{1, 2+t, 1-t+t^2,2-t^2\}$, a basis for $P_3$, the space of the polynomials with degree less or equal than $3$.

So, originally I though of taking, for example, $\{1, 2+t,2-t^2\}$. As this vectors are linearly independent, they are a basis for $P_3$.

But then I though, didn't that set of vectors needed to have a polynomial of degree 3 in order for those vectors to generate $P_3$?

Comment: Yes, you definitely need a 3rd order polynomial based on this definition of $P_3$.

Comment: So I just say that these vectors cannot generate $P_3$?

Comment: Something is wrong. Either they meant to say $P_2$ and their definition is correct or they meant to define $P_3$ to be the space of polynomials with degree strictly less than $3$ or they meant to include a vector with $t^3$ term.

Comment: Don't worry about trying to generate $P_3$ if you can't even generate $t^3$ from what you've got there!

Comment: You said your self " the space of the polynomials with degree less or equal than 3"- polynomials of the form ax^3+ bx^2+ cx+ d.  Do you see that this is a vector space of dimension [b]four[/b]?  Any basis must include [b]four[/b] vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If these are supposed generate the space of polynomials of degree less than *or equal to* $3$, that means that one of the generators should be a polynomial of degree $3$. So this set cannot possibly generate it.